# How to change the angular reactive forms based on selected option of the dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

All, I am trying to create an Screen for our internal request/Contact form for the support.So We have three different category(Network, Software and Other). So after the agent entering the details of his/her email/name then he selects the category. So if the User selects the Network then form should the input text bars for (Name,Email, ID and remarks) if they select 'Software' (Input bar below the Items should have (Name, Email, Software, Version, LAn and remarks) If they select the 'Others' the the options would be same as 'Network' option. Once user enter submit. will post the data to api and process it.

So here how can i achieve the form changes based on the selection of the option from dropdown in angular reactive

Please help

Here is the link of stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wq3qqt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ngIf and and take the values from dropdown to compare .I made this example for the software. For the cases that the form control exists on all cases no need to use ngIf.

***ngIf="profileForm.get('item').value == 'Software'"**

**[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m4rryl)**

```
 <form [formGroup]="profileForm"(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <h1>Contact Form</h1>
  <div >
    <label>
     Your Name:
     <input type="text" formControlName="yourname">
     </label>
    </div>
 <div>

<label>
  Your Email:
   <input type="text" formControlName="youremail">
  </label>
 </div>


<div>
   <label>
   Items:
  <select id="Item" formControlName="item">
    <option *ngFor="let c of item" [ngValue]="c">{{ c }}</option>
</select>
</label>

</div>

 <div>
 <label>
  Name:
 <input type="text" formControlName="name">
  </label>
 </div>
 <div>
 <label>
   Email:
   <input type="text" formControlName="email">
  </label>
  </div>
 <div *ngIf="profileForm.get('item').value == 'Software'">
 <label>
 Software:
 <input type="text" formControlName="software">
 </label>
 </div>

<div *ngIf="profileForm.get('item').value == 'Software'">
<label>
 Lan:
 <input type="text" formControlName="lan">
</label>
</div>

<div *ngIf="profileForm.get('item').value == 'Software'">
  <label>
   Version:
 <input type="text" formControlName="Version">
</label>
</div>
<div *ngIf="profileForm.get('item').value == 'Software'">
<label>
Remarks:
<input type="text" formControlName="remarks">
 </label>
 </div>

<button type="submit" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid">Submit</button>


</form>
```